# What should I do when Delphi imports WSDL improperly due to a hyphen in an enum name?

Tags: xml, delphi, class, proxy, wsdl

I'm using Delphi and I'm using a wsdl file from another company to set up my proxy class to use their data from their web service.  The wsdl file contains the following:

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="departStatus">
  <xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:documentation>Enumerates allowable departure statuses (DEPARTED, NOT-DEPARTED)</xsd:documentation>
   </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value="DEPARTED"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="NOT-DEPARTED"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
```

When I generate the proxy class I get the following:

```
  departStatus = (
      DEPARTED, 
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute('NOT-DEPARTED')]
      NOTDEPARTED);
```

Which doesn't compile unless I remove the line starting with [System.xml..., and it will not recognize "NOT-DEPARTED" as a valid value for departStatus.  If I change "NOT-DEPARTED" to "NOT_DEPARTED" in the wsdl file and any incoming xml file it works fine, but the company that set this up is insisting that "NOT-DEPARTED" is valid and will not change it.  Why isn't setting up the departStatus enumeration properly?  Any ideas how to get around this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which version of delphi are you using?

Comment: @RRUZ: this question was tagged `.net` before :)

Comment: @mjn,the op says `I'm using Delphi and I'm using a wsdl file...`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the WSDL?

Comment: @RRUZ: somebody using the account RRUZ removed the `.net` tag - look at the source code, this is obviously not Delphi Win32

Comment: Also, I'm told by techie peple at the other company that Visual Studio and C# do support hyphens so they are telling me to fix the roblem on my end rather than change the enumeration definition in the wsdl file.

Comment: I don't see the link to the WSDL in your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a possible workaround:

Since `departStatus` is of the base type `xsd:string`, you should be able to change all occurences of the `departStatus` type to `xsd:string` in the WSDL file.

That way you can pass/interpret the string `'DEPARTED'` or `'NON-DEPARTED'` instead of using an enum.

Comment: Can you expand on how I would do this, I'm very new at dealing with xml files.  What change should I make in the proxy class code?

Comment: I wouldn't change the generated code, I'd rather change the wsdl file. Search for all occurences of `departStatus` and replace them with `xsd:string` then remove the code fragment your gave in your question from the wsdl file. The proxy code should then have a string type instead of the enum type.

Comment: Bingo! Worked like a charm!  It is a 'work around' but it does the trick.  I owe you a big one.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi SOAP Runtime and Importer Update

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535

Comment: I tried this and, assuming I installed it correctly, it made no difference.

Comment: @Bob, it doesn't replace the ide's wsdl importer. You have to use the downloaded wsdlimp.exe from the command line (don't worry about any command-line arguments for now).

Answer (score 0):

If the Delphi(.Net) runtime does not support hyphens in enumeration names, I would create a basic test application using Visual Studio and C# to find out if it works there. Depending on the result I would consider to write a 'proxy' service which can be consumed from Delphi(.Net). If the C# web service support fails with the same error, then as a last resort a Java proxy could be an option.

Another idea: filter the web request/response HTTP data and convert the spelling "on the fly".

Comment: I'm using Delphi 2005 and following is a link to a ZIP file that contains the wsdl and xml files: http://www.mimosa.iom.int/confluence/download/attachments/51839154/movementservice.zip

Comment: I'd try Delphi 2007(.Net) if I could get a copy. Maybe Soap support is fixed there.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you would "filter the response HTTP data and convert the spelling on the fly"?  I'm new to xml processing and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is it Delphi or Delphi .Net 2005?